# SQL clustering without WSFC (Windows Server Failover Clustering)

Tags: windows, sql, cluster

Is it possible to cluster, or make SQL "highly available" without having to pay the huge enterprise prices?

By the looks of it, any type of SQL clustering requires enterprise edition Windows Server. We have a small mom and pop shop that just wants the database to automatically fail over if any issues arise, **without any user intervention required**, as the IT company is about an hour away.

I know you can use SQL Standard edition for a 2-node cluster, but do you need Windows Server Enterprise to get WSFC?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the latest versions of Windows Server to support Failover Clustering on Standard Edition - namely Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2012 R2.